# How to start pfctl at boot

Tags: macos, firewall

Before El Capitan I used to enable `pfctl` at boot by adding `-e` to the start up parameters.

In `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`

```
<string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>pfctl</string>
    <string>-e</string>                <---- this line
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
</array>
```

Now I am not able to edit the file anymore (because of System Integrity Protection).

Is there a way to achieve the same without disabling System Integrity Protection?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve the same without disabling System Integrity Protection?

Yes*, in System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Firewall Options..., check "Enable stealth mode" and turn on Firewall.

Somehow this enables PF. You can check by running `sudo pfctl -s info`.

*Tested on High Sierra and Mojave